# Find out hosting Uri when selfhosting JobHost

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

I'm trying to self host a `JobHost` using `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` and including the Http extension but I can't seem to figure out what Uri/port it is hosting on

This is my Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

    var filter = new LogCategoryFilter();
    filter.DefaultLevel = LogLevel.Trace;

    config.LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
        .AddConsole(filter.Filter);

    var httpExtensionConfiguration = new HttpExtensionConfiguration();
    config.UseHttp(httpExtensionConfiguration);


    if (config.IsDevelopment)
    {
        config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
    }

    var host = new JobHost(config);
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

and here is the output window when running

[image]

Comment: By default, JobHostConfiguration seems not enable use of ``UseHttp`` extension method, can you share more information about **Http extension** that you are using?

Comment: The extension is here https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/tree/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.Http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the HTTP Extension will add the required bindings, services and HTTP features, it does not provide a listener, so it won't setup the host for you (it relies on an external listen you'd need to setup).

With the Azure Functions runtime, the WebHost itself is the listener. The CLI uses that implementation in order to spin up the host and expose HTTP functions. You can see this approach here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/blob/f0e8121c51569d8d0551fbb9bb81fbed5a9ad64c/src/Azure.Functions.Cli/Actions/HostActions/StartHostAction.cs#L102-L112

You could have a simpler approach if you don't want to rely on the Script WebHost (the CLI leverages many of its features, so it makes sense there) by simply providing your application directly when building the host. You can look at the `Startup` class provided by the CLI to see how things are registered and configured with the latest bits:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/blob/ff45a85c462c6f1e83e04dcba13da8bcca7099c5/src/Azure.Functions.Cli/Actions/HostActions/StartHostAction.cs#L349-L374

**NOTE:** The extension version you're using, as well as the code I've shared are pre-release (or not even merged yet), so they're subject to change, but that's the direction we're going.